# Lottie animation in a RecyclerView playing the animation only on a single item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, lottie

I am doing a Lottie animation in Android RecyclerView, but the animation is playing only on a single item and always it is the last item. The onclick is on the correct item, but view of animation is on constant item.

my adapter portion

```
listingRecyclerItemBinding.quickviewfilled.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            quickViewNew("OFF", mValues.get(position).getPropertyIndex(),
                    mValues.get(position).getDeveloperId(), mValues.get(position).getPublic());
            mValues.get(position).setQuickAccess("0");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    listingRecyclerItemBinding.quickviews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listingRecyclerItemBinding.quickviews.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listingRecyclerItemBinding.addToquick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listingRecyclerItemBinding.addToquick.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    listingRecyclerItemBinding.addToquick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    quickViewNew("ON", mValues.get(position).getPropertyIndex(),
                            mValues.get(position).getDeveloperId(),
                            mValues.get(position).getPublic());
                    mValues.get(position).setQuickAccess("1");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });
            listingRecyclerItemBinding.addToquick.playAnimation();
        }
    });
```

How can I deal with the Lottie animation in android recycler view?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ? If yes, please share the solution.

Comment: I have a recyclerview where each item will have to play different lottie animation, but right now all the items are playing the same lottie animation. How to solve this problem ? Can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last element is the only one working, and the other interactions behave correctly,  the most probable cause is  your code reassigning/recycling your lottie animation alongside the RV until it reaches the last RV element, and being the last one to reassing/reuse, it's the one works.

Comment: i'd need access to the whole code and i'm at work right now so i'll be unable to check it for the next 10h atleast, but i hope it's a good enough hint to find it for yourself

Comment: How to solve this issue ?